# how to make a report act like a bill

Tags: vb6, report

1. i have a form it's purpose to view a client (client table) and a number of orders (order table)
   i need when the user build the order to a client the user can press a button called print bill so the report shows out and the name of client appear in the head section from the client table, and the order in the body section(it could be a 100 item ordered), and the total discount in the footer section

i know the query `"Select * from order where id = '"& Txtid.Text  &"'"`
but i cant do it, it only require a pure sql command without Txtid.Text
So how to include the `Txtid.text` within the query?

1. how can i send a whatever query and the result came out in a report, i only can make a command and build a report on it, so it must be a way to change the command from the code so the report view the data dynamiclly

Comment: Have you actually tried sending the string you have there?  If `id` is the primary key of the table then it should only return one order. The string you have will basically take the value from the `Txtid` object on your form.

Comment: i have two id, one for the order and one for the item (product), it could be more than one order so i do it by make the first id all withe the same number of the client when i have the bill i have only the id of the client so i can call his name and what he ordered by "select * from order where id = '"& Txtid &"'"

Comment: PS: It's not good practice to concatenate values directly from a text box.  [See this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: lets forget about the form, how about aprametar so i can pass value to the sqlString and use it in the (data environment > command > sql statment) so i can build the report on it

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to select multiple items.

Try adding a `ListBox` to your form with multiple selection enabled.  You could then concatenate all of your IDs from the `ListBox` into a string and use the `IN` comparator for your criteria, like so:

```
sqlString = 
    "SELECT " & _
        "field1, " & _
        "field2, " & _
        "fieldn " & _
    "FROM " & _
        "order " & _
    "WHERE " & _
        "ID IN (" & concatListIds & ") "
```

Comment: graet, but how about aprametar so i can pass value to the sqlString?

Comment: [Here's a pretty good tutorial](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-ado-and-stored-procedures-vb6) on using parameters with VB6 and ADO. As for selecting values from the `ListBox`, the values are static, so you should be able to just work through the list collection for the `ListBox` and build a string that way - [see this article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/14/listbox-control/6/).

Comment: that was very useful using a listbox + button well maybe the stored procedures is an advanced level for me to understand but thanx

Comment: It's the way to go, Maged - you'll find that most development using TSQL based databases use stored procedures to manipulate data in and out of the database.  Glad you enjoyed the read, it'll pay dividends later.  :o)

Comment: @MagedEzzat: Is the answer correct?  Would you mind confirming that it is if so?